# In which step should we reproject a LiDAR Dataset using LAStools when extracting DSM and DTM?

Tags: qgis, lidar, epsg, lastools

I have a lidar dataset from which I am trying to extract a DSM and a DTM (in meters) from it for EPSG 32614 (WGS84). Below info:

```
lasinfo (220926) report for 'C:\LAStools\bin\Data\Cornfield Non\Backup 5\Raw\cloud92e02583c4eed578.las'
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            1
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.2
  system identifier:          'REpJLUwxLURlbGwtNTc1MC4='
  generating software:        'DJI TERRA 3.10.6.0'
  file creation day/year:     195/2022
  header size:                227
  offset to point data:       1677
  number var. length records: 3
  point data format:          3
  point data record length:   34
  number of point records:    85751920
  number of points by return: 84817070 911128 23722 0 0
  scale factor x y z:         0.0001 0.0001 0.0001
  offset x y z:               3194320.982963833026588 9168216.618123717606068 77.185868757605689
  min x y z:                  3193840.1478 9167933.5993 44.6628
  max x y z:                  3194801.8181 9168499.6370 109.7089
WARNING: stored resolution of min_x not compatible with x_offset and x_scale_factor: 3193840.147787707392126
WARNING: stored resolution of min_y not compatible with y_offset and y_scale_factor: 9167933.599270919337869
WARNING: stored resolution of min_z not compatible with z_offset and z_scale_factor: 44.662826671902295
WARNING: stored resolution of max_x not compatible with x_offset and x_scale_factor: 3194801.81813995866105
WARNING: stored resolution of max_y not compatible with y_offset and y_scale_factor: 9168499.636976515874267
WARNING: stored resolution of max_z not compatible with z_offset and z_scale_factor: 109.708910843309084
variable length header record 1 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34735
  length after header  96
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 11
      key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeProjected
      key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsArea
      key 1026 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 58 value_offset 0 - GTCitationGeoKey: NAD83(2011) / Texas Central (ftUS) + NAVD88 height (ftUS)
      key 2049 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 12 value_offset 58 - GeogCitationGeoKey: NAD83(2011)
      key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 3072 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 6578 - ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey: NAD83(2011) / Texas Central (ftUS)
      key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9003 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Foot_US_Survey
      key 4096 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 6360 - VerticalCSTypeGeoKey: NAVD88 height (ftUS)
      key 4097 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 21 value_offset 70 - VerticalCitationGeoKey: NAVD88 height (ftUS)
      key 4098 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 5103 - VerticalDatumGeoKey: Vertical Datum Codes 5103
      key 4099 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9003 - VerticalUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Foot_US_Survey
variable length header record 2 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34737
  length after header  92
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoAsciiParamsTag'
    GeoAsciiParamsTag (number of characters 92)
      NAD83(2011) / Texas Central (ftUS) + NAVD88 height (ftUS)|NAD83(2011)|NAVD88 height (ftUS)| 
variable length header record 3 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'liblas'
  record ID            2112
  length after header  1100
  description          'OGR variant of OpenGIS WKT SRS'
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X            -4808352    4808352
  Y            -2830189    2830189
  Z             -325230     325230
  intensity           0        255
  return_number       1          3
  number_of_returns   1          3
  edge_of_flight_line 0          0
  scan_direction_flag 0          0
  classification      0          0
  scan_angle_rank   -35         35
  user_data           0          0
  point_source_ID     0          0
  gps_time 341930759.933908 341931289.757861
  Color R 0 65280
        G 0 65280
        B 0 65280
WARNING: 2 points outside of header bounding box
number of first returns:        84817070
number of intermediate returns: 23690
number of last returns:         84817572
number of single returns:       83906412
overview over number of returns of given pulse: 83906412 1774379 71129 0 0 0 0
histogram of classification of points:
        85751920  never classified (0)
WARNING: real max y larger than header max y by 0.000047
WARNING: real min y smaller than header min y by 0.000047
```

I am using the following workflow (tools):

- las2las (to modify scaling factors and offset factor)
- lasplit (to split dataset)
- lasground (to classify dataset) using -feet -elevation_feet
- las2las (to remove either ground points or non-ground points)
- lasnoise (to remove noise) using -feet -elevation_feet
- las2dem (to convert to tif & reproject)

Currently I am doing the reprojection in the last step of the workflow, but this seems not to be correct. QGIS does not overlap this reprojection with similar files I know they are in EPSG 32614.

Answer (score 3):

I had never before used lastools to reproject, so I was going by [This](https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/WKmAxSHuZH8) when I said las2las wouldn't re-project. But I tried just now to use las2las to re-project a EPSG:6578 NAD83(2011)/Texas Central(ftUS) laz file to EPSG:32614 WGS84/UTM zone14N(Meters). It landed where it was supposed to. That said, I do not know if it handled the NAD83(2011) to WGS84 Datum shift correctly. To use lasdatum requires either an NTv2 grid file or seven parameter helmert transform parameters, neither of which I know where to find.

I used this command:

las2las -cpu64 -i "D:\Download\Liberty Hill\stratmap21-50cm_3097173d3.laz" -target_utm 14N -target_precision 0.01 -odir "D:\Download\Liberty Hill" -odix "_32614" -olaz

For best advice you might want to post in the [LAStools Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/lastools).

Comment: I have the license, that is not a problem. Your answer will be accepted if you mention when it should be converted (beginning of workflow, end of workflow?). Giving the command would also be helpful.